# @testing-library/react import error with Parcel 2 + Jest + TypeScript stack

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, parceljs

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-cohen-hgb98

When I run this same setup locally, I get a TS error message on the `@testing-library/react` import:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
```

[image]

I thought this might be something to do with the `esModuleInterop` flag but as you can see, I have that enabled. I'm stumped. Any help would be super appreciated.

I'll continue fiddling with the sandbox till I can repo it in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this has taken me hours and sods law I figure it out when I post it. It turns out I had the `automock` option enabled in my jest config which was breaking this  (ofc).

Hopefully this helps someone else I guess!